# multiprocessing with a global variable (a function) defined inside another function and using local variable

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables, pickle

I made some tests about this setting, that appeared unexpectedly as a quick fix for my problem:

I want to call a `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` from inside a `main` function (that sets up the parameters). However it is simpler for me to give a locally defined function as one of the args. Since the latter can't be pickled, I tried the laziest solution of *declaring it as global*. Should I expect some weird results? Would you advise a different strategy?

Here is an example (dummy) code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import multiprocessing as mp


def processfunc(arg_and_func):
    arg, func = arg_and_func
    return "%7.4f:%s" %(func(arg), arg)


def main(*args):
    # the content of var depends of main:
    var = random.random()

    # Now I need to pass a func that uses `var`
    global thisfunc
    def thisfunc(x):
        return x+var

    # Test regular use
    for x in range(-5,0):
        print(processfunc((x, thisfunc)))

    # Test parallel runs.
    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        for r in pool.imap_unordered(processfunc, [(x, thisfunc) for x in range(20)]):
            print(r)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

PS: I know I could define `thisfunc` at module level, and pass the `var` argument through `processfunc`, but since my actual `processfunc` in real life already takes a lot of arguments, it seemed more readable to pass a single object `thisfunc` instead of many parameters...

Answer (score 1):

What you have now looks OK, but might be fragile for later changes.

I might use `partial` in order to simplify the explicit passing of `var` to a globally defined function.

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

def processfunc(arg_and_func):
    arg, func = arg_and_func
    return "%7.4f:%s" %(func(arg), arg)

def thisfunc(var, x):
    return x + var

def main(*args):
    # the content of var depends of main:
    var = random.random()
    f = partial(thisfunc, var)

    # Test regular use
    for x in range(-5,0):
        print(processfunc((x, thisfunc)))

    # Test parallel runs.
    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        for r in pool.imap_unordered(processfunc, [(x, f) for x in range(20)]):
            print(r)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```